# Applescript save to clipboard instead of Desktop

Tags: applescript

I found this Applescript that takes a screenshot and saves the file to the desktop.

I want the code to save the screenshot to the clipboard instead of the desktop.

```
set currentDate to (do shell script "date +'Screen Shot %Y-%m-%d at %H.%M.%S'")

set tmpFile to "/tmp/sourcefile.png"

set the clipboard to "This is going onto the clipboard."

set outputFile to quoted form of (filePath & currentDate & ".png")

try
    
    do shell script "screencapture -i -s " & tmpFile
    
on error
    
    return
    
end try

try
    
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/convert " & tmpFile & " \\( +clone -background Black -shadow 50x10+5+5 \\) +swap -background none -layers merge +repage " & outputFile
    
on error
    
    display dialog "An error occured. Review your script and try again." buttons {"OK"} default button "OK"
    
end try
```

Comment: Have you considered keystroking `Cmd+Ctrl+Shift+3`?

Comment: I didn't mention that the script adds a drop shadow to a selection and saves it to the desktop.  The selection made using the OSX shortcut Cmd+Shift+4 doesn't include a drop shadow.

I want the selection with the drop shadow copied to the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (it's in the man file):

```
do shell script "screencapture -c"
```